# Type another answer in JSON enum FormFlow dialog

Tags: botframework

I am using JSON FormFlow dialogs.

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var activity = await argument;
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                context.Call(FormDialog.FromForm(() => BuildJsonForm(), FormOptions.PromptInStart), DialogCompleted);
            }
        }
public static IForm<JObject> BuildJsonForm()
    {


        using (var stream = File.OpenRead("my.json"))
        {
            var schema = JObject.Parse(new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd());
            return new FormBuilderJson(schema)
                .AddRemainingFields()
                .Build();
        }
    }
```

Inside of [my.json](https://www.dropbox.com/s/togghcdxd56mpzr/my.json?dl=0) I have enum:

```
"properties": {
"EnumExample": {
  "Prompt": { "Patterns": [ "To what language translate {||}" ] },

  "Describe": { "Image": "" },
  "type": [
    "string",
    "null"
  ],
  "enum": [
    "en",
    "fr",
    "ru",
    "de",
    "es"
  ],
  "Values": {
    "en": {
      "Describe": "English"
    },
    "fr": {
      "Describe": "French"
    },
    "ru": {
      "Describe": "Russian"
    },
    "de": {
      "Describe": "German"
    },
    "es": {
      "Describe": "Spanish"
    }
  }
}
```

**The question** : how I can support selecting by user one of Enum options and also free text typing , so I can run another dialog or run Luis API on that input. For example user will type " I want to talk with operator" instead of answering Enum in my JSON FormFlow dialog?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call LUIS from FormFlow in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004803/call-luis-from-formflow-in-c-sharp)

Comment: The duplicate I posted should answer your question